# Design: ensuring clean separation of rendering of a response from a response

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns, servlets

This is a design / patterns problem. I have a service which now also needs
to be exposed as a RESTful web service.

Within the existing code i have the concept of a Request, a suite
of possible ServiceOperations (strategies) and the return of any ServiceOperation is
a Response object. This approach decouples the inner workings of the
service from the presentation medium (Custom TCP Server, HTTP REST, HTTP
SOAP etc.).

I've now started to implement a MyServiceRESTfulServlet which looks something
like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        /* Wrap an http servlet request with an adapter which hides all
         * the messy details of an HttpRequest and exposes a nice interface
         * for working with MyService
         */
        IRequest serviceRequest = new MyServiceRESTfulRequest(httpRequest);

        /* There's nothing HTTP related in this part, it's the exact same
         * code you'd find in other presentation formats. A Response has
         * no idea about HTTP, TCP Servers or the like.
         */
        Response serviceResponse = dispatchRequest(serviceRequest);

        /* A static helper which knows the interface of a Response
         * and can translate that into REST-speak for feeding back via
         * an HttpServletResponse.
         */
        renderRESTfulResponse(serviceResponse, httpResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletExcetion(e);   // Caught by a seperate
                                        // RESTfulErrorServlet
                                        // configured in web.xml
                                        // Rendering an appropriate
                                        // response.
    }
}
```

My problem is a Response can be one of 2 kinds currently:

```
public enum ResponseKind() {
    BINARY, METADATA;
}
```

For binary, my restful response helper will render one way, for metadata
it will need present the metadata appropriately - an HTML table, a JSON
blob, etc.

Figuring out what type is easy - a Response object exposes a
getOriginalRequest() which after appropriate checks can be cast to a
MyServiceRESTfulRequest which exposes a .getAcceptablePresentation() - an
enum:

```
public enum RESTPresentationKind() {
    HTML, JSON, XML, PROTOBUF_MYSERV_0.1;
}
```

How best can i keep this rendering code decoupled from a Response object.
In future no doubt other kinds of response will be possible. As is,
renderRESTfulResponse() goes raiding through the Request object and builds
writes out the data appropriately. It's very tightly coupled to both the
Response interface (which i'm ok with) but it knows to go poking through
the Request object too.

I just don't feel i've done this bit in as clean and maintainable a way
as i have the rest of this service. I'm "special casing" for each of the
possible response types, and each of the possible response formats. Feels
uber-hacky.

Can you suggest any way to cleanly process rendering a RESTful response
given a presentation-agnostic Request object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not implement the rendering on your RepsonseKind enum (enums are really classes) or dispense with ity entirely? When you find yourself trying to get rid of case/switch statements, the answer is usually either composition + overloading + Command pattern or the Visitor pattern.

Comment: ResponseKind would then have baggage about HTTP REST, but that wouldn't make sense when it's used in a TCP Server context. Visitor pattern looks interesting.

Comment: Just have ResponseKind implement more than one interface. Or have it emit an instance of the type that will handle the processing, minus the HTTP/REST baggage. The latter would be more "single concern" compliant.